# The input that i give to my %f does not save

Tags: c, math, average

The gradeOne and secondGrade does not save the number that i give. So i cant have the average , because, always end in a division of (0 + 0)/2, can anyone help me?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
    int students;
    char name[50];
    double gradeOne, secondGrade, classAverage = 0, average = 0;

    for(students = 1;students <= 15; students++){
        printf("Tell me Your name: \n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%[^\n]s", &name);
        //saves name
        printf("Tell me your first grade: \n");
        scanf("%f", &gradeOne);
        printf("Tell me your second grade: \n");
        scanf("%f", &secondGrade);
        //saves grade


        printf("\n========================================\n");

        printf("Student: %s\n", name);
        printf("First Grade: %3.2f \nSecond Grade: %3.2f \n", gradeOne, secondGrade);
        printf("%f", average);

        printf("\n========================================\n");

        average = (gradeOne + secondGrade)/2;
        //creates average
        printf("Average of the %d student: %3.2f",students, average);

        classAverage += average;
        //creates class average

    }
        classAverage = classAverage / (students - 1);
        printf("The class average was: %3.2f", classAverage);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The behavior of `fflush(stdin);` is undefined.  Once your program has exhibited undefined behavior, there's no point in further analysis.

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s", &name)` is incorrect.  Almost certainly you intended to use `"%[^\n]"`.   With the trailing `s`, if the next line of input begins with an `s` it will be matched and consumed by this.

Comment: I suggest `" %[^\n]"` and it should be `name`, not `&name`

Comment: Use `scanf(" %49[^\n]", name)`, else might as well use the evil `gets()`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell "With the trailing s, if the next line of input begins with an s" is amiss.  `"%[^\n]"` consumes any `'s'` of input.  The `"s"` in `"%[^\n]s"` is superfluous.

Comment: Boropap, Tip: the biggest problem is not compiling with all warnings enabled.  Save time.  Enable all warnings or use a better compiler.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Ah, yes, to match the 's' on the next line the string would have to have whitespace between the `]` and the `s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%f` in `scanf()` is for reading `float`. You should use `%lf` to read `double`.

Note that you should use `%f` in `printf()` for *printing* `double`. Newer specification allows `%lf` for `printf()`, but `%f` should be better for compatibility.

Comment: This is worth mentioning too: `scanf("%[^\n]s", &name);`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Then also `fflush(stdin);`

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see that one. Interesting :-)